# FTDI connection to ESP32 S3 for read/write

Tags: esp32, ftdi

I am trying to read/write to an ESP32S3 module (ESP32-S3-WROOM-1U) using the below FTDI.

[image]

I've set the jumper on the FTDI to VCC & 3V3. Here's a connection I tried, but it doesn't work. I've done it for both UART 0 and UART 1 pins. For the connections here, I only list the ones for UART 0.

```
FTDI VCC -> ESP32S3 3v3
FTDI GND -> ESP32S3 GND
FTDI TXD -> ESP32S3 U0RXD (GPIO44)
FTDI RXD -> ESP32S3 U0TXD (GPIO43)
FTDI RTS -> ESP32S3 U0CTS (GPIO16)
FTDI CTS -> ESP32S3 U0RTS (GPIO15)
```

Another connection I've tried is this, which also doesn't work.

```
FTDI VCC -> ESP32S3 3v3
FTDI GND -> ESP32S3 GND
FTDI TXD -> ESP32S3 U0RXD (GPIO44)
FTDI RXD -> ESP32S3 U0TXD (GPIO43)
FTDI RTS -> ESP32S3 IO0 (GPIO0)
FTDI CTS -> ESP32S3 EN (EN)
```

Lastly, I've tried this, and it also doesn't work.

```
FTDI VCC -> ESP32S3 3v3
FTDI GND -> ESP32S3 GND
FTDI TXD -> ESP32S3 U0RXD (GPIO44)
FTDI RXD -> ESP32S3 U0TXD (GPIO43)
GND -> ESP32S3 IO0 (GPIO0)
```

This is the command I'm running, which reads off the mac address from the ESP32S3.

```
esptool.py --chip esp32s3 --port /dev/cu.usbserial-A10OEN33 --baud 115200 read_mac
```

How can I get the FTDI working so I can read/write to the ESP32S3?

Comment: Do you know what connections the Python code needs? If it uses DTR output to go into bootloader, it does not have that pin. Or at least if it does then it is not marked.

Comment: don't power the esp32 from the 3.3 V pin of an FTDI. it can' provide enough power. did you put the esp32 into bootolader mode?

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem, but i found a solution:
You have to desolder the two resistors (0 Ohm) connecting TXD and RXD from CP2102N on the ESP32-S3-DEVKITC-1 to TX and RX on ESP32-S3-WROOM-1 so you do not have any contact to the CO2102N and then connect you external FTDI as usual:
FTDI     ESP32-S3
3V3       3V3
GND       GND
TX        RX
RX        TX
but every time you want to upload your code on the ESP32-S3 you should first press the BOOT button and keep pressing simultaneously press RESET button then let RESET first then let the BOOT button too and you should see on the serial motitor the following:
waiting for download.

I hope this helps you and you solve your problem.

Greetings